# Operator as function pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, function-pointers, functor

I would like to have a class implement `operator()` several different ways based on an option set in the class. Because this will be called a large number of times, I don't want to use anything that branches. Ideally, the `operator()` would be a function pointer that can be set with a method. However, I'm not sure what this would actually look like. I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
  int (*operator())();

  int DoIt1() {
    return 1;
  }

  int DoIt2() {
    return 2;
  }

  void SetIt(int i) {
    if(i == 1) {
      operator() = &Test::DoIt1;
    } else {
      operator() = &Test::DoIt2;
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  Test t1;

  t1.SetIt(1);

  std::cout << t1() << std::endl;

  t1.SetIt(2);

  std::cout << t1() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I know it will work if I create another function pointer and call that from the `operator()` function. But is it possible to have the `operator()` function itself be a function pointer? Something along the lines of what I posted (which doesn't compile)?

The above code gives:

> test.cxx:5:21: error: declaration of ‘operator()’ as non-function
>
> test.cxx: In member function ‘void Test::SetIt(int)’:
>
> test.cxx:17:16: error: ‘operator()’ not defined
>
> test.cxx:19:16: error: ‘operator()’ not defined
>
> test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> test.cxx:30:19: error: no match for call to ‘(Test) ()’
>
> test.cxx:34:19: error: no match for call to ‘(Test) ()’

Comment: `int (operator())();` ... correct syntax ?

Comment: Hrm, it should be `int (*operator())();` I think, but that just raises a whole other set of errors. I'll edit the code.

Comment: " I don't want to use anything that branches. Ideally, the operator() would be a function pointer" - Actually, branches are better for performance. Modern CPU's have a better than 50% success rate in predicting which branch will be taken; function pointers can point anywhere and are therefore far harder on the prediction logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class needs to somehow remember what function pointer to use. Store it as a class member:

```
class Test
{ 
public:
    Test() : func(0) {}

    int operator()() {
        // Note that pointers to Test member functions need a pointer to Test to work.
        return (this->*func)(); // undefined behavior if func == 0
    }

    void SetIt(int i) { 
        if(i == 1) { 
            func = &Test::DoIt1; 
        } else { 
            func = &Test::DoIt2; 
        } 
    }

private:
    int DoIt1() { 
        return 1; 
    } 

    int DoIt2() { 
        return 2; 
    } 

    // Typedef of a pointer to a class method.
    typedef int (Test::*FuncPtr)(); 
    FuncPtr func; 
};
```

However, before you go into the effort of doing this, *profile your code first* and see if branching via `switch` or `if` is actually a bottleneck (it might not be!). Modern processors have very counterintuitive performance characteristics, so compilers may be able to generate better code than you think it does. The only way to  make sure that branching is actually too costly for you to use is to profile your code. (And by "profiling" I mean "run well-designed experiments", not "come up with a hunch without testing".)

Comment: `typedef int (*FuncPtr)(); ` is incorrect. You need to write `typedef int (Test::*FuncPtr)(); `

Comment: There is still problem. You need to write `(this->*func)();`, not just `func();`.

Comment: I knew it was possible to create another pointer to store the function that `operator()` called, I was just wondering (or maybe hoping?) that it could be avoided. Also, this is for a numerical code and will be on the inner-most loop of a 4D array that has hundreds of millions of iterations... so I know branching will be a problem.

Comment: I think we just had the same idea, but you just backed yours up with sample code. +1 to you. Another +1 if I could for pointing out the futility of doing this without profiling; a `switch` statement would probably be fastest anyway.

Comment: @Nawaz: I can only edit so fast. :-P I don't use function pointers often.

Comment: @tpg2114: When you say you know, did you actually run experiments and produced data to verify what you know? Because anything and everything you know is useless without evidence. If you can produce evidence in your favor, that only makes your case for using branchless code stronger. If the evidence is against your favor, it means you will waste your time with this function pointer stuff.

Comment: @Insilico: There is another solution if you don't want use member-function pointers. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `operator()` an inline function which calls another pointer. The optimizer should take the extra indirection out completely.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is provided by @In silico which is valid in both C++03 and C++11.

Here is another solution for C++11 only:

```
std::function<int(Test*)>  func;

func = &Test::DoIt1; 

func(this); //this syntax is less cumbersome compared to C++03 solution
```

[A quick online full demo](http://ideone.com/l88eB)